# Compare DATETIME column date with current date in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a DATETIME column that stores values such as:

2012-05-20 14:00:00

How do I compare the date in `$row['Date']` with current date (time is not important) to see if it's older than today?

```
if($row['Date'] < ...) {
echo 'date has passed'
}
```

Comment: You could do the compare in the database, too, and then just check that column in the result.

Comment: You want to knock the time off the $row['Date'] var to compare actual days. So: if( strtotime( substr( $row['Date'], 0, 10 ) ) < strtotime( date( "Y-m-d" ) ) ) print "That's so old";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not have SQL do the comparison for you?

```
SELECT *, DATE(`Date`) < DATE(NOW()) AS is_old ...
```

Then you've got a column called 'is_old' which is 1 if the date is before today and 0 if it's not. So, in PHP, all you need to do is something like:

```
if ($row['is_old']) {
    // handle the old date case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime($row['Date']) < time() + 60 * 60 * 24;
```

We add the extra day (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours) to time() to effectively ignore the hours/minutes/seconds as you requested

It's that simple :D You can add offsets and stuff quite easily too:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: That doesn't take into account `20012-05-20 14:00:00` in which the time is to be ignored.

Comment: The strtotime function includes the seconds in the calculation, if you posted this before I updated it to include strtotime then yeah - I fixed that :D

Comment: No, I posted it after. Think about it, and reread the question: *to see if it's older than current day*.

Comment: Hmm... both strtotime and time return UNIX Timestamps, both of which are focussed on seconds. Is it because 20012 is too large? IDK... What are you seeing that I'm not?

Comment: Or are you talking about the capital D for date that I forgot to include?

Comment: You have to *ignore* the time, and use just the date. In both. It needs to be `2012-05-10 < 2012-05-10`, not `2012-05-10 14:00:00 < 2012-05-10 8:29:27` in unix timestamp format. The OP wants to ignore the time in the comparison, and what you have doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: if currently it's `2012-05-20 14:00:00` and the posts date is: `2012-05-20 12:00:00`. This condition will include the post in the results and it shouldn't since it's from the same day. I only want to compare the dates.

Comment: You could also `strtotime('+1 day')`, and the time won't matter.

Comment: Oh - I see. Didn't manage to read that in the question. Strange, I notice the capital D in date but not the larger (time not important). Thanks for that

Comment: Well, actually I think the `strtotime('+1 day')` might not work. Ignore that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - "you have to _ignore_ the time"...so `$date_parts = explode(' ', $row['Date']); $result = strtotime($date_parts[0]) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d', time()));` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```php
if( $row['Date'] < date('Y-m-d') ) {
 echo 'date has passed';
}
```

Comment: If it's `20012-05-20 14:00:00`, that won't work if the time is to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to convert the MySQL date string to the format PHP understands time values:

```
$date = strtotime( $row['date'] );
```

Then, you can compare it with the current time,

```
if ( $phpdate < time() ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very old question but still it may help somebody. 
`SELECT * FROM tbarticle WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) > 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2018-01-01 21:48:46)'`
Note the single quotes, 
**time** is a column name.
we use it following way:
 `$sql="SELECT * FROM tbarticle WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) > 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP($urlTime)'";`
replace the $urlTime with current date time